# Is there a way to use ES6 syntax in a React Outlook Add-in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook-web-addins

We're building an Outlook Add-in with React. As our main app is built with React too, we want to use the same code for both. And a lot of code is written with ES6 syntax.

The add-in works well in those environments:

- Outlook Webmail (Chrome, Safari, Edge)
- The latest version of Outlook from Office 365

**But not in Outlook 2016 or 2013**. I guess the latest version of Outlook uses Edge for rendering the Add-in, that's why it works. 2013 / 2016 are with IE11, which do not support ES6.

There is a lot of code with a lot of dependencies and I don't want to translate all in non-ES6, it will take too much time.

The fact is that our main app works well in IE11, with the help of [react-app-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill). With those two lines at the very beginning of the index.tsx file, it works:

```
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
import "react-app-polyfill/stable";
```

I did exactly the same in our add-in, but we still get a blank page when we open it on the older versions of Outlook. The main difference between the web app and the add-in is that the first one was created with create-react-app. The add-in is configured with webpack.

Did I miss something? If you need more information or code, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently developping an Outlook add-in for Outlook 2016 Desktop (which is using IE11) and I can use ES6 features.

Did you use yeoman and generator-office to create the boilerplate for the project?

Like @philipp said, you will have to use a transpiler like babel to convert it down and configure your bunbdler (e.g. webpack) to use that transpiler for js/jsx files.

```
// webpack.config.js
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: [
                    'react-hot-loader/webpack',
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            ...
         ],
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new in react / webpack, and I used the default webpack configuration generated by office, without really understanding what it meant. Instead of `babel-loader` it was `ts-loader`. I installed babel and it works now (and I understand a bit more what I'm doing now). Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are building a react app you should have some kind of pre-processor/bundler like webpack in place. Just drop in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/setup) and transpile it down ES5. This way you have to transform the code by hand and can share the same code base even for legacy engines.